# Tcl regsub issue

Tags: regex, tcl, regsub

I'm trying to write a TCL script to regsub a string within the contents of a file.

The string I'm searching for is a hexadecimal value denoted as X"12312312"
I want to replace this string with another hexadecimal value, for example X"ABCDEF12"

As the hexadecimal value will change each time I run my script, I want the search to wildcard what's in between the quotes.

If I test my regsub as follows:-

`regsub X"*" $content X"ABCDEF12"` (where $content is the file I've read in)
The regsub is succesfull, however when I inspect $content it has updated the hex value as follows:-

X"ABCDEF12"11223344"

can anybody please guide me as to what I'm doing wrong?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Please try regsub {X"[0-9A-Fa-f]+"} $content X"ABCDEF12"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the [`*` quantifier](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.html#M7) is wrong; you need to provide some atom that the quantifier applies to, e.g., `.` for any character; better:

```
regsub -nocase -- {X"[A-Z0-9]*"} $content X"ABCDEF12"
```

Also, you want to set the case sensitivity explicitly!

---

### Update

As Donal suggests, you may turn on case-insensitive matching using an [embedded option `(?i)`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.html#M86) like:

```
regsub -- {(?i)X"[A-Z0-9]*"} $content X"ABCDEF12"
```

Comment: You can also use a `(?i)` flag inside the RE to enable case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt response @mrcalvin, I can see where I've gone wrong now!

Comment: Can also use `[[:xdigit:]]` instead to match just hex digit characters.